# Adjustable Font size

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Font size in content areas is too small to be comfy for me. Please make it customisable.

Functional areas are ok because I don't have to actually read them to know what's there.

Comment: @DavidPostill what kind of settings do you mean? The question is about iOS app. Browser settings don’t affect it.